# Git status local has mismatch with git status in Microsoft Git Provider for VS 2013

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

My Microsoft Git Provider for VS 2013 shows a Pending Delete in Solution Explorer.

In contrast, if I run `git status`, Git tells me my local is clean, I also have nothing stashed.

I have tried (to no avail):

- closing VS 2013, turning off the MS Git Provider in the IDE.
- `git reset --hard`

The file in question was renamed via the IDE and it is the renamed version [the one I am keeping] that shows as a pending delete in the IDE.

This status is also showing up in a colleagues' machine.